# Skipping two Convolutional network through residuals in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

I wanted to know how could we connect the convolutional layers to form Residuals.This is my VGG16:

```
#Initialising the CNN
cls=Sequential()

#adding 1st Convolution2D layer
cls.add(Convolution2D(64,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(120,120,1)))
cls.add(Convolution2D(64,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))

#adding 1st pooling layer
cls.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid'))

#adding 2nd Convolution2D layer
cls.add(Convolution2D(128,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))
cls.add(Convolution2D(128,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))

#adding 2nd pooling layer
cls.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid'))

#adding 3rd Convolution2D layer
cls.add(Convolution2D(256,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))
cls.add(Convolution2D(256,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))
cls.add(Convolution2D(256,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))

#adding 3rd pooling layer
cls.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid')) #15

#adding 4th Convolution2D layer
########################connection start#########################

cls.add(Convolution2D(512,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))

cls.add(Convolution2D(512,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))

#########################connection end#########################

cls.add(Convolution2D(512,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))

#adding 4th pooling layer
cls.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid'))

#adding 5th Convolution2D layer
cls.add(Convolution2D(512,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))
cls.add(Convolution2D(512,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))
cls.add(Convolution2D(512,(3,3),strides=1,border_mode='same',activation='relu'))

#adding 5th pooling layer
cls.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid'))

#Flattening
cls.add(Flatten())

#Full connection1
cls.add(Dense(output_dim=2704,activation='relu'))
cls.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Full connection1
cls.add(Dense(output_dim=2000,activation='relu'))
cls.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Final Layer
cls.add(Dense(output_dim=10,activation='softmax'))

#Compiling CNN
cls.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])#'adam'
```

I want to connect the two layer as shown in the code - #connection start and end

Comment: Indent four spaces to create an escaped `<pre>` `<code>` block. The text will be wrapped in tags, and displayed in a monospaced font. The first four spaces will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved. You can select a block of code and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> to automatically add four spaces to the beginning of every selected line. For more information see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

The `Sequential` model in Keras - as the name indicates - has a strictly linear flow. For your code to work, you will have to make use of the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

In short, you will have to define a (slightly more complicated, but still manageable workflow), where you assign intermediate results to variables, which you can then combine to use as inputs in later layers, thus creating your residual layer.

There is also a [nice gist](https://gist.github.com/mjdietzx/0cb95922aac14d446a6530f87b3a04ce) showing how something like residual layers can be implemented.